# How to pass touchUpInside function as parameter in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a dynamic UIButton and I want to set listener dynamically to the button. But I get error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'myFuncName(sender:)'

My code (you can paste it into Xcode and run):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        add my button
        let button = Btn()
        button.setListener(buttonTapped)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        print("tapped")
    }
}

//    -------------------------------
class Btn: UIControl {
    fileprivate let button: UIButton = {
        let swapButton = UIButton()
        let size = CGFloat(50)
        swapButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
        swapButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return swapButton
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    func setListener(_ listener: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Error - Use of unresolved identifier 'listener(sender:)'
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(listener(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a method that looks like `func listener(sender:Any)`

Comment: This method passed from `ViewController` with `button.setListener(buttonTapped)`. I want to throw `buttonTapped` method as parameter to the `Btn class` and set `buttonTapped` as touchUpInside listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think there is something wrong with the approach. UIButton is the subclass of UIControl and you're trying to do something that is something not legit. In short, you are creating an object of child class in the parent class itself.

Solution: In my opinion you might wanna subclass UIButton instead of UIControl. For example.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    // Properties
    var closure: () -> Void = {
        /// empty initialization
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    // methods and selectors
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        // Your Code.
        self.closure()
    }

}
```

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    //Outlet of your custom button.
    @IBOutlet weak var button: CustomButton!    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.closure = self.buttonTapped
    }

    public func buttonTapped(){
        print("Code Works...")
    }    
}
```

explanation:

1. In the code above we sub classed UIButton and declared a property in it. which is a type of a function that returns void.
2. Then we added target to a function the UIButton subclass. Which will execute a function "button tapped", every time the button is tapped.
3. Then we directly assign the function to the property "closure". ('var closure' is a property of a function type that returns void.)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I try your code in xcode 9 and it not works.

Comment: Hey, @Slava I just have edited the above code and have tested it too. Please try the above approach as this time it will surely work. I just have simplified the whole code. If it doesn't I'll send you my demo project if that can help.

Comment: It is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`#selector` creates a `Selector` that points to a function.  If you want to call your custom listener code block, you will need to assign it to a instance var of `Btn`, then call it from a private function.

```
let button = Btn()
button.listener = {
    // your closure here
}

class Btn: UIControl {
    weak var listener: (() -> Void)?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.listener?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try your code, but it not works. `buttonTapped` not fired. I try to move listener to setTargetMethod, but it not works too.

Comment: You will need to set `self.userInteractionEnabled = true` in your `Btn` class.

Comment: I added `self.userInteractionEnabled = true` and code not works too. Do you try to run this code?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        add my button
        let button = Btn()
        self.addListener(to: button, using: #selector(buttonTapped))
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        print("tapped")
    }

    func addListener(to button: UIButton, using handler: Selector) {
        button.addTarget(self, action: handler, for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

The above code is what I believe you are trying to achieve. The point of the `addTarget` method is to tell the control what class (the target; `self` in this case), the method (action), and when the method should be called (`.touchUpInside`). Here, we are saying i want to call the `buttonTapped` method in the `ViewController` class whenever `button` receives the `.touchUpInside` event.

Comment: OP appears to be writing a convenience button that will execute a code block rather than having to catch `touchUpInside`, but is using it as if passing a selector.

Comment: @Samah I don't see that in the question.

Comment: OP is defining `func setListener(_ listener: @escaping () -> Void)` and assuming they can pass a `Selector` instead.  Solution is to either define the argument to `setListener` as a `Selector`, or to write it such that it executes a code block.

Comment: @dudeman Thank you for your answer. I thought about solution such as in your example. But it is my experiment and I'm trying how to pass function as parameter and set it as `touchUpInside` listener. Maybe in real projects my variant how to do this thing will be weird. But I only learn swift for a few days and I experimenting with it.

Comment: @Slava I updated my answer to give an example of how to pass a method as a parameter to another method.